# sdp file content for broadcasting a tv channel in android app

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

Hi, I am trying to create  an android application which will live stream tv channel. I found some sdp files on internet http://gillbinder.wapka.mobi/site_174.xhtml.
When I run this code

```
VideoView view=new VideoView(this);
setContentView(view);
 view.setMediaController(mediaController);

             view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://simplelive.nexg.tv:554/starplus_mpeg.sdp"));

             view.start();
```

I can view live stream of star plus channel in my phone. I read about SDP(session Description Protocol) is used for describing the streaming content. I saw some sdp file examples for streaming a video and stream a video in vlc media server. I dont know what should be the sdp file code for broadcasting a tv channel.

For example I want to know the code for starplus_mpeg.sdp file in rtsp://simplelive.nexg.tv:554/starplus_mpg.sdp so that I will be able to make my own sdp file for some other tv channels like aajtak(http://aajtak.intoday.in/livetv.php). Can someone help me how to make these sdp files?

Answer (score 0):

make your SDP files by using either [curl](http://snipplr.com/view/57846/curl--rtsp-to-get-sdp-descriptor-for-media-stream/) or [openrtsp](http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/streaming/2004-November/001917.html) to Call 'DESCRIBE' on rtsp protocol and parse the response to get your sdp file..

http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/streaming/2004-November/001917.html